# How do i delete a record from SQLite using "name" for example instead of id?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, tkinter

> I have a code below which Deletes records from the database using the "email_address" when i use the Id, it deletes fine, but when i switch it to "email_address" it gives me a sqlite3.OperationalError. I have an input field which stores the data that is going to be deleted and is passed down below as "email_delete". Does anyone know how to fix it?[This is the link to the image which contains the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5AN4.png)

```
def removeEmail():
conn = sqlite3.connect("email.db")
c = conn.cursor()
if c.execute("DELETE from email WHERE email_address =(?)" + email_delete.get()):
    deleted_email = Label(
        root, text="You have been Unsubscribed from the mailing list"
    )
    deleted_email.grid(row=5, column=0)
else:
    error_label = Label(root, text="There is no such record")
    error_label.grid(row=5, column=0)

email_delete.delete(0, END)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of errors or code. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the relevant information. Images aren't searchable and may go away, making this question useless for others.

Comment: Thanks fro the feedback, stack overflow didn't not let me post the image becuase "im dont have enough repution or something" or i wasnt planning on pasting the link. Thanks again for the feedback

Comment: He means that it would be better to copy the text of the error message and stack trace and paste it into the question rather than using an image. That way, others who are searching for the text of your error message can find this post, and there's no chance of an image being unlinked from the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the values that will replace the placeholders in your query as a second argument to `c.execute(...)` instead of concatenating them together with the query string:

Instead of

```
c.execute("DELETE from email WHERE email_address =(?)" + email_delete.get())
```

do

```
c.execute("DELETE from email WHERE email_address=?", (email_delete.get(),))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback. It works now thanks !! :)